# Selling Multi VMs in Azure MarketPlace

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

I have created Data Service API which Store and retrieve data from four types of databases. All DBs, API are deployed in different VMs and Data Service API uses public IPs to communicate with these DBs. Now I want to pack all these DBs and Service API in single unit and sell in Azure Marketplace, While searching I have found terms like cluster, Virtual Private Network, but I have no idea how can i deploy these things and sell in marketplace.

So what architecture should i follow to deploy which is suitable for azure marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking to have more of a SaaS offering, and often that is not something you can "bundle" or "package" like a simple VHD or VM.

In my opinion, most of the real SaaS applications in the Azure marketplace are more like "ads" than "packages". Often they take you to the vendors website where they have more control over their "product". You can specify the home page of your product to be a site you maintain, and surface your offering in a way that makes sense. Look to the Azure marketplace as a way for folks to find you, not a way for them to provision your offering.

I would setup your infrastructure in Azure using whatever IaaS/PaaS elements you need, and look to your own website as the "front end". Here are the details:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partner-program/